# Failed to resolve: play-services-phenotype with Firebase Remote Config and Firebase Performance Monitoring

Tags: android, firebase

When I try to add two libraries, I get the following error when trying to sync gradle:

```
Failed to resolve: play-services-clearcut
Open File


Failed to resolve: play-services-phenotype
Open File
```

Here is my project-level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        /*classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc2'*/
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

    }
}
```

And this is the app-level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

...

dependencies {
    //Firebase dependencies
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the failure.  Do your dependencies include any `com.google.android.gms:play-services-xxx` libs?

Comment: It may not help here, but I recently saw a build problem that was resolved by changing the order of repositories, putting `google()` before `jcenter()`, as is [shown in the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#top-level).

Comment: Reordering fixed the issue. It's quite a wired issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently ran into this problem and after a lot of trial an error, figured that it was just the order of the jcenter() and google(). I know its stupid, but the answer will help someone struggling with same problem. Credit to @Bob Snyder as well for pointing it out in the comment.

Your code should look like this:

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
```